# Nuget feed in VSTS "Including description is not supported while including all versions."

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, nuget-spec

I created a nuget feed in my VSTS and I follow the instructions to push a package but I'm getting this error consuming it from Visual Studio:

> "[CGPE.LogClient3] Failed to retrieve metadata from source
>   'https://cgpe.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/30074c7b-4682-48db-9c97-9afd15e93471/nuget/v3/query2/?q=&skip=0&take=26⪯release=false⊃portedFramework=native,Version=v0.0&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
>   Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server
>   Error - Including description is not supported while including all
>   versions. (VSTS Activity ID: 1C80CF12-0FE0-4757-A230-1461A7C07A2F))."

Also, I get a "No packages found" performing a nuget list.

> nuget list -Source
>   https://cgpe.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/CGPE.LogClient3/nuget/v3/index.json
>   Please provide credentials for:
>   https://cgpe.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/CGPE.LogClient3/nuget/v3/index.json
>   UserName: Vicente 
>   Password: ****************************************************
>   No packages found.

But the package is pushed

> nuget.exe push -Source
>   https://cgpe.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/CGPE.LogClient3/nuget/v3/index.json
>   -ApiKey key "VSTS-HelloWorld\VSTS-HelloWorld 1.0.55.nupkg" Pushing VSTS-HelloWorld 1.0.55.nupkg to
>   'https://cgpe.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/30074c7b-4682-48db-9c97-9afd15e93471/nuget/v2/'...
>
> PUT
>   https://cgpe.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/30074c7b-4682-48db-9c97-9afd15e93471/nuget/v2/
>
> Please provide credentials for:
>   https://cgpe.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/CGPE.LogClient3/nuget/v3/index.json
>
> UserName: Vicente Password:
>
> Conflict
>   https://cgpe.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/30074c7b-4682-48db-9c97-9afd15e93471/nuget/v2/
>   14828ms
>
> Response status code does not indicate success: 409 (Conflict - The
>   feed already contains 'VSTS-HelloWorld 1.0.55'. (VSTS Activity ID:
>   CD8E6A2A-2F0E-4F8C-8768-42EDCE269083)).

I can't find any information about this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new simple package? What's the result if you push to a new feed? What're packages in that feed? Do you delete the packages? Can you provide the screenshot?

Comment: I have reproduced the steps with the sample package provided by Microsoft and I get the same result. I have pushed to a new feed and I get the same result (note the name of the feed is CGPE.LogClient3, then there are two more feeds). I'm able to delete the package and after that, I'm not able to push the same package with the same version, but this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Can you share a sample package on the OneDrive?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: You can share it on the OneDrive.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @ThomKiesewetter Can you share a sample package on the OneDrive?